# How to have rows from related tables as nested json objects in a node.js API

Tags: node.js, api, rest

I'm trying to build my first Rest-API using node.js, swagger and mysql.

I have two tables in mysql database: Banco (0:1) --> Conta (1:N).

I want my API to return an array of a JSON objects of Banco rows, each containing a field "Conta" containing all related Conta objects, like:

```
{
  "bancos": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nome": "Banco 1",
      "Conta": [{"nome": "Conta 1"},{"nome": "Conta 2"}]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nome": "Banco 2",
      "Conta": [{"nome": "Conta 3"},{"nome": "Conta 4"}]
    }
]}
```

I'm using **mysql pooling** object.

```
// const sql = require('tedious');
const dbConfig = require('./dbConn').config;

const pool = new sql.createPool(dbConfig);

exports.execSql = function(sqlquery, params) {
    // var params = [];
    // params.push(id);
    sqlquery = sql.format(sqlquery, params);
  
    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
      pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) rej(err);
        connection.query(sqlquery, function(err, rows) {
          if (err) rej(err);
          else res(rows);
          connection.release();
        });
      });
    });  
}
```

This is my Banco **controller**, that uses the Banco and Conta models. Each one return a promise with the their queries (simple selects).

```
'use strict';
var Banco = require('../models/banco');
var Conta = require('../models/conta');

module.exports = {getBancos};

function getBancos(req, res, next) {
    let idUsuario = 1; //example
    Banco.getAll().then(result => {
        if (!result.error){
            if (result.length){
                result.map(banco => { 
                    Conta.getAll(idUsuario, banco.id)
                        .then(resultado => {
                            banco.Conta = resultado
                            // res.json({bancos: resultado}); --> note1: if I use this, the result is quiet ok, but it raises an error of resending the headers.
                        })
                }); 
                res.json({bancos: result}); //--> note2 --> here results just the Bancos objects with empty .Contas [], because it does not wait the promise to be resolved 
            }
            else
                res.status(204).send();
        }
        else
            res.status(result.error.status || 500).send(result);
    });
}
```

Assuming my structure is ok, I wonder how to manage the flow as I could have the objects Bancos with their Contas atributes populated with the result of Conta.getAll()?
Any idea?

Thanks for helping...

Rafael

(let me know if more information are required)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried more stuff and could realize how to solve this: basically it is about to put the .map() inside a **Promisse.all()** and an **await** for the function that brings the rows. It ends up like this:

```
function getBancos(req, res, next) {
    let idUsuario = 1;
    Banco.getAll().then(result => {
        if (!result.error){
            if (result.length){
                Promise.all(result.map(async banco => { 
                    banco.Contas =  await Conta.getAll(idUsuario, banco.id)
                        .then(resultado => {
                            if (!resultado.error && resultado.length >0){
                                return resultado;
                            }
                            else return []
                        });
                })).then(() =>{ 
                    res.json({bancos: result});
                }); 
            }
            else
                res.status(204).send();
        }
        else
            res.status(result.error.status || 500).send(result);
    });
}
```